# iOS Framework size increases after minor changes in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I am creating an iOS framework project which is basically an SDK for a system we are developing. I followed [this](http://codefriend.blogspot.in/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html) guide to create a universal framework bundle of the SDK.

The first time I built the framework bundle, its size was 2.1MB. After that I kept making very minor changes in the code for optimizations and bug fixes and now the framework size has increased to 3.4MB. I do not link against or include any external library or framework, I did not add any extra files to the project and the code optimizations and bug fixes are merely minor replacements to existing code. I have also tried 'clean' and 'clean build folder' every time but for some reason, after every iteration the framework bundle size keeps on increasing.

I do not have a problem with the size of the framework bundle, but I would like to understand, what causes the bundle size to increase significantly after negligible changes in code. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something here?

PS: I am using Xcode 5.1

Comment: You could disassemble your code before and after you make a change. That should show you exactly what is different.

Comment: Have you tried doing diffs between different builds of the framework bundle to determine what has changed?

Comment: if you are using git repo while creating your project then try using `$git diff` command and it will show you the difference in your project.

Comment: @ThomasW, I have only paid attention to the diff in the code so far, I'll dig a little deeper this time, thanks for the hint.

Comment: things to consider - 1. number of different architectures supported by your sdk. 2. did you strip off debug information other debug related information from the final result ? 3. clean cache. 4. decompress any uncompressed files from final assembly and compare them.